# In the conda environment list, what does the asterisk mean?

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I am learning about conda and I am trying to verify I understand the notion of the "active" environment as opposed to ... something else I don't understand.

In particular, `conda env list` or `conda info -e` will list environments and always seems to put an asterisk next to one of them, like here where it puts it by the "base" environment:

```
$ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/alexis/miniconda3
mynotebook               /Users/alexis/miniconda3/envs/mynotebook
```

But this does *not* mean the base environment is currently active, as I can see by doing `conda info`:

```
$ conda info | head -3

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
```

So if the asterisk does not indicate the active environment, what does it indicate?

Answer (score 5):

You are very close to having the full understanding. The * does indeed mean the active environment, which *in the absence of specifically activated environment* **is** the base.

Consider the following

```
$ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/alexis/miniconda3
mynotebook               /Users/alexis/miniconda3/envs/mynotebook
$ conda install pandas
```

Without activating a conda environment, the base *is* active in this instance, and pandas will be added to the base 'environment'.

Whereas

```
$ conda activate mynotebook
(mynotebook)$ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
base                      /Users/alexis/miniconda3
mynotebook            *   /Users/alexis/miniconda3/envs/mynotebook
(mynotebook)$ conda install pandas
```

Will install into the specific environment that is activated.

Comment: Are you sure about this? If the "base _is_ the active environment", then how come `conda info -e` says the active environment is "None"? And how come doing `source activate base` changes my shell prompt and PATH, so that `type python` returns a different result before and after I activate it? If it was already active, then activating it would have no effect -- no?

Comment: base is not active -per-se unless you do conda activate (or source activate)

however, in the absence of a specifically activated environment, base 'earns' the asterisk.

There's no difference between

conda activate
conda info -e

and

conda activate base
conda info -e

Comment: Re-reading this now, a year later, trying to understand this same issue, it seems like you're saying there's a difference between a "specifically activated environment" (selected with the activate command) and what we might call the "asterisked environment" (which is either the specifically activated environment, or another environment if nothing is specifically activated). So there are two concepts here.

Comment: Why doesn't it say `active environment : base`, then?